# Does Banshee support Last.FM iPod scrobbling?

Tags: banshee

Does Banshee support Last.FM iPod scrobbling ?
Rhytmbox does!

Answer (score 2):

Not currently: see [Bug 536389](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=536389).  It's a commonly requested enhancement, but so far no one has offered a patch, and this doesn't seem to be a high priority for the core developers.

Comment: Banshee isn't really iPod friendly. I find it hard to understand you can't even copy a simple playlist to it from Banshee.

Comment: I'm unable to test it, but it looks like it's possible now. [Bug 536389](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=536389) is listed as resolved and fixed. On the bug page a Banshee developer stated: "The feature is now in master branch."