# Ipod scrobbling to last.fm?

Tags: amarok

The Amarok 1.4 series scrobbled the songs I played via ipod (and also had great ipod song transfer functionality). I've not been able to scrobble songs played via my ipod then synced to a media player since my upgrade to 11.10 (and the subsequent total loss of Amarok 1.4).

I see various media players (clementine, banshee) have requests in for this feature but I'd like to believe that something, somewhere has ipod scrobbling in Ubuntu! Was the 1.4 series of Amarok the only thing that had it? Good music management is one of the main reasons I've used Linux (besides stability, clean interfaces, ease of development, etc). The lack of ipod scrobbling to last.fm makes me a very sad panda.

Answer (score 1):

No need to look far, good old [Rhythmbox](http://projects.gnome.org/rhythmbox/) does it! And Banshee now does it too! See: [Does Banshee support Last.FM iPod scrobbling?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47827/does-banshee-support-last-fm-ipod-scrobbling/198165)

Answer (score 0):

I find the [songbird](http://www.getsongbird.com/) support for last.fm to be more than adequate. But admittedly I don't use it for scrobbling my iPod.

There is also [Amarok 2](http://amarok.kde.org/), though my experience of it was that is lost a lot of features in the transition (ah the joys of open source). However, it is being constantly developed.